# ReSharper run all tests instead of a single one that is selected

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper, resharper-10.0

**I use ReSharper 10 and NUnit 3.**

When I run my tests in Visual Studio all is good. But **when** I select a single test in ReSharper **and** run it **or** debug it **then** not the selected test is run but all the tests.

The same happens if I select a test in `Resharper - Unit Tests - Unit Tests` window or if I select it in the code (click on the icon at the left side of the test: http://prntscr.com/a1clt1

All my methods marked with `[Test]` attribute or `[TestCase()]` attribute

Is it a bug of ReSharper, of NUnit or maybe it can be set in settings?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install R# 10.0.2 build (the latest available [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/)), it is fixed there https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450313.

Comment: Now some of my tests can't be run... it tells they are inconclusive:(